# Javascript Recursive Function doesn't work for arranging data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

When I run this code, for some reason I believe the recursive arrange method is not doing the right thing. Any of the inner groupings are not present in the output for the filter function. What am I doing wrong with functional javascript?

```js
const def = x => typeof x !== 'undefined'

const filter = ([x, ...xs], fn) => def(x)
    ? fn(x)
        ? [x, ...filter(xs, fn)] : [...filter(xs, fn)]
    : []    

let arrange = t => {
  return { num: t.id, groups: t.groups.map(arrange) }
}

let data = [
  {id: 1, groups: [{id: 3, groups: []}]},
  {id: 4, groups: []},
  {id: 5, groups: []}
]
   
let groups = data.map(arrange)

console.log(groups)
// => [ { num: 1, groups: [ [Object] ] },
//      { num: 4, groups: [] },
//      { num: 5, groups: [] } ]

let getById = g => {
    if (g.num === 3) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
}

let filtered = filter(groups, getById)

console.log(filtered)
// []
```

Comment: Can you provide a JS fiddle?

Comment: Or better yet, a stack snippet

Comment: Well `filter` does not traverse into the objects at all?

Answer (score 1):

Before filtering you have to flatten the nested entries into a flat list:

```
 const flatten = groups => groups.flatMap(group => [group, ...flatten(group.groups)]);
```

That way you can easily do this:

```
 const result = filter(flatten(groups), byID);
```

to get an array of groups.

---

To maintain the tree order you'd have to recursively filter:

```
const advancedFilter = predicate => array => array.map(predicate).filter(it => it.take).map(it => it.value || it);

const use = (a, v) => v(a);

const filterGroups = predicate => advancedFilter(group => use(
  filterGroups(predicate)(group.groups), 
  filtered => ({ take: predicate(group) || !!filtered.length, value: { ...group, groups: filtered })
));

const result = filterGroups(byID)(groups);
```

*Note that `flatMap` is very new, so you might not want to use it in production without a transpiler...*

Comment: This works, however I want to maintain the recursive tree structure in the data, and this seems to break that. 
    [ { num: 1, groups: [ [Object] ] },
      { num: 3, groups: [] },
      { num: 4, groups: [] },
      { num: 5, groups: [] } ]
Maybe the way I'm recursing in the arrange function is not the best way?

Comment: @eric so your expected result is `{ num: 1, groups: [{ num: 3, groups: [] } }` ?

Comment: Yes, I need groups to maintain it's recursive structure just like that, actually the filtering isn't even important I just used that to show the problem(unable to access nested groups)

Comment: @eric there you go